# Tomboy won't start: Configuration server couldn't be contacted

Tags: gnome, gentoo, d-bus, glib

I'm unable to start [Tomboy](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy) on my Gentoo Linux system.  It used to work, but now I just get `Unhandled Exception: GLib.GException: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: Method "GetDefaultDatabase" with signature "" on interface "org.gnome.GConf.Server" doesn't exist` and a stack trace.

`/usr/libexec/gconfd-2` is running as my user.

I'm not sure what else to look at.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More searching suggested that logging out and back in to create a new desktop session would resolve the problem.  I tried it and it worked.

Apparently, even though `gconfd-2` was running, it wasn't hooked up to D-BUS properly.